# Is it Arrays.asList ( ) method support the char[ ] array?

Tags: java, arrays

We can use Arrays.asList( ) method for String[ ] and Integer[ ] arrays. Can we use the char[ ] array in Arrays.asList( ) method?

```
Arrays.asList(75,85,95,70);
Arrays.asList("String", "Integer", "Character");
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added a tag for the specific language you are using. Most people here follow specific tags, so you'll get better, more targeted answers.

Comment: By the way, you should understand that the `char` type is essentially broken since Java 2, legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters. To work with individual characters, use code point integer numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is conflating arrays with varargs arguments.

In your example:

```
Arrays.asList(75,85,95,70);
```

the `75,85,95,70` is not an `Integer[]` or an `int[]`.  It is actually a sequence of `int` values for a *varargs* parameter.

What actually happens is that the `int` values are autoboxed to `Integer` values and these are then assembled into an `Integer[]`.  (The autoboxing and array construction happens at the call site!)

The `Integer[]` is then passed to `asList` method with `Integer` as the inferred type parameter `T`.

---

So to answer question that you asked:

> Is it `Arrays.asList()` method support the `char[]`  array?

Yes and no.

On the one hand:

```
  List<Character> charList = Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c');
```

will compile and give you a list of characters in the same way that your `int` example does.  Note that the result is a `List<Character>` rather than a `List<char>`.

One the other hand:

```
  char[] test = char[]{'a', 'b', 'c'};
  Arrays.asList(test);
```

will produced a `List<char[]>` with a single list element.  Indeed, if you have an actual `char[]` (as distinct from a sequence of `char` parameters), then `asList` **cannot** convert that to `List<Character>`.

Answer (score 0):

The Java char keyword is a primitive data type. So that's why we can't simply convert it.

You can do it as below
First convert char array to string then map it's chars to list

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.List;
char[] chars = {'c','d','e', 'f','g'};
        List<Character> cahrList = String.valueOf(chars).chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You can also write `List<Character> cahrList = Arrays.asList('c','d','e', 'f','g');`.

Comment: But that is not wrapping an array of `char`.  The arguments to `asList` are being autoboxed to `Character` **before** the call to `asList`.   So it is actually a `Character[]` that is being wrapped!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Character` class for char primitive data type:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TestCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Character> charList = Arrays.asList('c','d','e', 'f','g');
        System.out.println(charList);
    }
}
```

Comment: But this is not a `char[]`.  The individual `char` arguments are autoboxed to `Character`.  The actual argument that `asList` gets is a `Character[]`.

Comment: you asked for it: `Can we use the char[ ] array in Arrays.asList( ) method?` read your question

Comment: you can use `charList.get(0).charValue()` to get char value back

Comment: Well ... yes ... you can get the `char` values back.  But my point stands, I think.